# data from simple java class to JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have simple java class . I am passing some data (eb.xyzabc) from this simple java class to servlet. Servlet gets this value. Now I want to pass the same data ie.xyzabc to JSP.

Technically I want to see the data (eg. xyz ) passed from simple java class to JSP immediately. 
Is it possible, if possible what I have to , how can I do this. Please help me. Thank you. I am using GlassFish Server. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("data", javaBean);
```

In your jsp

```
${data.property}
```

Comment: @ int21h , Thank for the reply . I am going to see and do whatever u told me and going to do some research on javaBean as well. But I have one question...The simple java class mentioned above is not related to Glassfish server,its stand alone program. so is it possible from idea u mentioned ?? similarly i want to pass that data immediately to JSP ??? Just wanted to make confirm ..Thanks again int21h.

Comment: Where I'm using "javaBean", you'd replace that with the object you want to use in your jsp. javaBean is just the name that I used here.  JavaBeans are java objects that follow specific conventions.  When your jsp is doing ${data.property}, what it's really doing is javaBean.getProperty() behind the scenes.  It's able to figure out what the getter method is because that's one of the conventions that 'java beans' follow.  And you can use this code in any servlet container, be it an application server such as glassfish, or a light container such as Tomcat.